# Why `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength` is different with same devices pair (iPhone 6s <-> iPad air) with/without same iCloud account loged in?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, icloud

Why the `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength` is different on the same pair of devices?

I am developing an app using bluetooth le to communicate with each other. The app was tested on an iPhone 6s and an iPad air. It crashed when we sent a packet which its length is exceeding `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength`. After fixing that issue, we found that the `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength` is different in different conditions.

With same iPhone and iPad as BLE central and peripheral:

1) with the same iCloud account logged in, iOS won't show the pairing process and the `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength` is 74. And none of each device is shown in the others `settings->bluetooth->my devices`

2) without same iCloud account logged in, then in the pairing process, iOS will ask the user to pair them. The `CBCentral.maximumUpdateValueLength` is 182. And the paired device is shown in `settings->bluetooth->my devices`.

I expect to have the pairing process in both conditions and the `CBCentral.maximumValueLength` should be the same.

I'd like to know why the payload length is shorter with same iCloud account logged in and how can I do to make the payload length works as none iCloud account logged in.

Thank you.

Comment: What did you wind up doing? I think you should be flexible and accept whatever is given. But that doesn't really answer your question. I think iOS at a lower level figures out what setting works best given the conditions at the time. Does it relate to signal strength, noise, other factors like this in the environment? I don't know.